# What does 'every monomorphism in $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ is a kernel' mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

In *Algebra: Chapter $0$* by Aluffi, at the end of page 161, he writes:

> Since every submodule $N$ is then the kernel of the canonical projection $M \to M/N$, our recurring slogan becomes, in the context of $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$
>   $$\text{kernel} \iff \text{submodule}:$$
>   unlike as in $\mathsf{Grp}$ or $\mathsf{Ring}$, being a kernel poses no restriction on the relevant substructures. Put otherwise, ‘every monomorphism in $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ is a kernel’; this is one of the distinguishing features of an abelian category.

I know what a monomorphism is:

In a category $\mathsf{C}$, a morphism $f: A \to B$ is a monomorphism if for any object $Z$ and any two morphisms $\alpha: Z \to A$, $\alpha': Z \to A$, we have $f\alpha = f\alpha' \implies \alpha = \alpha'$.

> **What does 'every monomorphism in $R$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ is a kernel' mean?**

Comment: It means that "every monomorphism is a kernel", that is if $f:A\to B$ is a monomorphism, then there is some morphism $g:B\to C$ with $f=\ker g$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you elaborate? If we are dealing with $R$-modules, what would it mean for the module hom $f$ to be the set $\ker g$?

Comment: If you are unsure of the definition of kernel, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(category_theory) .

Comment: Though we usually just refer to the object part of a kernel, a kernel is not just an object. Given $g:B\to C$, the kernel of $g$ is an object $\ker g$ *and* a *morphism* $\ker g\to B$. You can easily prove that this morphism is always a monomorphism. The statement is saying that conversely, every monomorphism is the morphism part of a kernel for $R\mathbf{Mod}$.

Comment: "A submodule is not a module, it's a monomorphism."

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a morphism $\phi:X\to Y$ with kernel $K$. In Aluffi, the emphasis is placed on the domain $X$, but the kernel is really both the object $K$ as well as the (mono)morphism $K \hookrightarrow X$.

Remember that in $\mathbf{Grp}$, $\mathbf{Ring}$, **and** $R–\mathbf{Mod}$, monomorphism $\iff$ injective. So an equivalent formulation to the statement in your question is that every injective morphism's domain is the kernel of some homomorphism.

The reason this is true in $R–\mathbf{Mod}$ is that given the morphism $X \to X/K$, its kernel is $K$! While in group, this is not necessarily the case, because $X/K$ is not a group if $K$ isn't normal. Thus, in $R–\mathbf{Mod}$ (and in $\mathbf{Ab}$), any injection's domain is the kernel of some morphism, but this is not true in general in $\mathbf{Grp}$.